# How to sort elements of ArrayList in ascending order? - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created a To-Do-List program where one of the actions requires the program to list all tasks input by the user in ascending order of the date that they fall on.

Output example:

```
Tasks listed in ascending order (earliest first):

TaskName, 20/04/2020, time, location, duration, category 
TaskName, 18/07/2020, time, location, duration, category 
TaskName, 09/08/2020, time, location, duration, category 
TaskName, 21/12/2020, time, location, duration, category
```

So far, with the code that I have, the tasks that the user input all list, but they don't list in ascending order of the date of each task.

Here is my code so far:

```
public void sortTasks() {

    System.out.println("Sorted tasks by date (earliest first): ");
    
    Collections.sort(currentList);
    
    currentList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your current approach to the problem makes it hard to achieve what you want. You have a list of Strings and want to parse some fragment of them and sort based on that. It is possible but you can make it much simplier. You already got a dedicated class to represent your `Task`. You should keep a `List` of `Task`s then, not their String representations.
When you have a `List<Task>`, there are couple of ways to sort it. You can either implement `Comparable` in your class or use a `Comparator`. You could do something like that:

```
currentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Task::getDate))
```

Or (depending on desired order)

```
currentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Task::getDate).reversed())
```

And then you use `getItem()` only when you want to print the results (such method is usually called `toString()`).

Comment: When I change the arrayList to type `Task`, I receive multiple new errors all throughout my program. Here is a fiddle: https://paiza.io/projects/tF9oVNIvPa9yWX5b8e6LtQ?language=java

Comment: @DrMe Because you keep using it as `List<String>`, you add a String at 182, and iterate over it as list at 144 and 246.

Comment: If I change the return type of getItem() to Task instead of String, then how do I return what was originally in that method?

Comment: @DrMe `getItem` should still return `String`. The thing is you should be adding `myTaskObj` to the list instead of `theItem`. Then in each place you want to use it as a `String`, you call `getItem` on the object in there.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle: https://paiza.io/projects/tF9oVNIvPa9yWX5b8e6LtQ?language=java How would I go about fixing the error in the `searchTasks()`? Also, after doing these changes, the tasks are still not printing in ascending order

Comment: @DrMe searing is a unrelated to your question, but you have to use `task.getDate()` there.

Comment: @DrMe You need to change how you are comparing dates for searching. I have included the complete code in my answer for your reference.

Comment: The code in your answer doesn't return the tasks in the correct sorted order. There is also an error in the `sortTasks()`: `The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments 
 (List<Task>)`

Comment: @DrMe Then you're probably calling it in some other way, not like I showed in the answer.

Comment: Here is my code currently https://paiza.io/projects/lIfuNvXa5rX6QSksRl7gYw?language=java

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to store `Task` objects not `String` in your list.

Usually you can pass a `Comparator` to `Collections.sort`.

```
Collections.sort(tasks, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

In order for that to work properly you have to make `Task` an implementation of `Comparable`, the way you compare the fields of the object depend on your specific task, here you can provide implementation for ascending comparison, and than reverse it by `reverseOrder` method.

```
class Task implements Comparable<Task> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Task task) {
        return Comparator
            .comparing(Task::getTitle)
            .thenComparing(Task::getDate)
            .compare(this, task);
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can create and pass to `sort` a more sophisticated `Comparator` object, without `Task` being a `Comparable` object.
Note though, that this approach makes code less reusable.

```
Collections.sort(tasks, 
    Comparator
        .comparing(Task::getTitle)
        .thenComparing(Task::getDate)
        .reverseOrder()
);
```

Also consider using `SortedSet` or `PriorityQueue` instead of `List` for your task in order to avoid explicit sorting and reduce algorithmic complexity

Comment: there is no task or dates lits, currentList is a list of string which store toString of Task object

Comment: @MohdWaseem clarified that

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you just maintain a `List` of `Task` instances and sort that `List`.

You can use one of the following options to sort a `List` of `Task` instances:

1. Implementing Comparable Interface
2. Using Comparator

### Implementing Comparable Interface

To implement `Comparable` interface, you must override `compareTo` method in `Task` class. Since you want to sort Tasks based on `date` instance field, you can just return the result of date comparison.

Here's how you should override `compareTo()` method to sort Tasks in ascending order based on `date` instance field.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Task o) {
    return this.date.compareTo(o.date);
}
```

Since `Date` class already implements `Comparable` interface, you can just call `compareTo` method to compare two `Date` instances.

Now to sort the list of tasks, call `sort` method of `Collections` class.

```
Collections.sort(taskList);
```

[Here's a version of your code](https://pastebin.com/4RvuJe2M) that implements `Comparable` interface and sorts the tasks using `date` instance field

### Using Comparator

There are more than one ways to sort objects using a `Comparator` interface:

- Create a separate class that implements `Comparator` interface
- Use anonymous class or use lambda expression
- Use static methods of Comparator interface

#### Create a separate class that implements Comparator interface

You can create a class that implements `Comparator` interface and then override `compare` function. Implementation of `compare` function will be same as that of `compareTo` function implemented above by implementing `Comparable` interface.

```
class TaskComparator implements Comparator<Task> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
        return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    }
}
```

To sort the task list, you have two options:

1. Use `sort` function of `Collections` class and pass an instacne of `TaskComparator` class as a second argument

   ```
   Collections.sort(taskList, new TaskComparator());
   ```
2. Use `sort` method of `List` interface

   ```
   taskList.sort(new TaskComparator());
   ```

[Here's a version of your code](https://pastebin.com/Pgyr6Yka) that creates a separate comparator class to sort the tasks using `date` instance field

#### Use anonymous class or use lambda expression

Instead of creating a separate class to implement `Comparator` interface, you can use an anonymous class

```
Collections.sort(taskList, new Comparator<Task>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Task t1, Task t2) {
         // code to compare Task objects
     }
});
```

or

```
taskList.sort(new Comparator<Task>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
          return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
      }
});
```

Java 8 introduced lambda expressions, you can replace anonymous class with lambda expression to make your code concise

```
Collections.sort(taskList, (o1, o2) -> o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate()));
```

or

```
taskList.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate()));
```

[Here's a version of your code](https://pastebin.com/gmMJWipB) that uses lambda expression to implement `Comparator` interface

#### Use static methods of Comparator interface

You can also use static method named `comparing` of `Comparator` interface. It will return a comparator that will be used for sorting.

```
Collections.sort(taskList, Comparator.comparing(Task::getDate));
```

or

```
taskList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Task::getDate));
```

[Here's a version of your code](https://pastebin.com/9mJRrnRV) that uses `Comparator.comparing` method to sort the tasks using `date` instance field

For details on how to implement `Comparable` or `Comparator` interfaces, see:

- [Comparable vs Comparator in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/)
- [Java Comparable interface](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparable-interface-in-collection-framework)
- [Java Comparator Interface](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework)

Comment: Only the first option is valid, a `Task` is not a comparator

Comment: currentlist is a list of string. There is no task list

Comment: Implementing `Comparator` in `Task` would be really weird. If anything, it should be some separate class.

Comment: OP's app only maintain `List<String> currentList`.  And `String` already implements `Comparable`.

Comment: @saka1029 yes i know but i have mentioned in my answer that it would be better to maintain a `List` of `Task` instances and sorting that list using one of the options mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Yousaf OP changed the type of `currentList` to `List<Task>`.  But he got many compilation errors.  See @Amongalen's answer and its comments.

Comment: @saka1029 i have included the fixed code in my answer

Comment: This still doesn't sort the tasks

Comment: @DrMe it sorts the Tasks correctly. I have tested the code. Try replacing your code with mine instead of copying some parts of my code into yours and also see the updated answer for details of different options for sorting tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `List` use `sort` method with custom `Comparator`

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Task::getDate).reversed());
```

But I think you have to use another collection. `PriorityQueue` feet better than `ArrayList`.

```
Queue<Task> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(...));
```

Comment: I can only see `List<String> currentList` as a list to sort.

Comment: Use `PriorityQueue ` with custom  string `Comparator `

Answer (score 0):

Since creating  TaskList and sorting based on dates solution is already provided by **@Amongalen**.

I will provide a different approach with better **Time complexity**. Since Sorting a collection can be **O(nlogn)**. It is not a good idea to sort after every time you add an element to the list.

Instead you can maintain a `PriorityQueue` of Task Object and compare them based on date and add `Task` objects to that `PriorityQueue`.

Now you don't need to call sort, just `iterate` over the `queue` and display the result.

```
PriorityQueue<Task> queue  = new PriorityQueue<>((o1,o2)-> o1.getDate.comapreTo(o2.getDate));

// Add task object to the queue
queue.add(myTaskObject);

//iterate and display when asked
Iterator<Task> it = queue.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(it.next().toString());
}
```

Note: adding task object to queue is O(logn)
So this will improve time of your solution